# Static file served through express sendfile takes route as the relative directory and not it's location directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a route in express

```
router.get('projects/fest', function(req, res, next){
    res.sendfile('fest.html', {root: './public'});
});
```

Going on `localhost:3000/projects/fest` displays the html file but css and image files are not loaded.

Checking the problem, the thing is all the relative locations that I have put in the fest.html file like `img src="images/1.jpg` are not trying to fetch data from `/projects/images/1.jpg`.

How to change the locale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express provides a built in middleware for serving static files. Assuming all your static files are in a directory structure under your-app-dir/public, but you want to request them using a url like localhost:3000/projects/images/1.jpg you can try something like:

```
app.use('/projects', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

For more info:

http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.static

http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html